# Dynamically read in python module from user selection once packed as exe

Tags: python

I have a python module with a list of array variables:

```
key1 = [0x01, 0x02]
key2 = [0x03, 0x04]
```

I can read it in and use like this:

```
my_module = importlib.import_module('keysAC')
print(mymodule.key1)
```

But I can't figure out how to do that such that the user can select the file once I have packed it using pyinstaller. I know pyinstaller can be told about 'hidden' imports but I would like the user to be able to select the file...or I would settle for just being able to read in a fixed filename from the current working directory.

Comment: Why not importing `keysAC` regularly: `import keysAC; print(keysAC.key1)` ?

Comment: I was doing that...but I moved to ```importlib``` as I thought I would be able to somehow make that dynamic. So, once it is packed in the .exe the import is already embedded in the exe but I want it to be read in when I run the .exe so it can be modified without need to rebuild the .exe.